# How to convert csv to select options

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript how convert string contains CSV value  like

```
1;option 1;2;Option 2;3;Option 3
```

To

```
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
```

Comment: where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I note is, it is in a single line. It would be better if the source is like:

```
1;Option 1
2;Option 2
3;Option 3
```

And once this is done, you need to get it by reading the file or getting it from user input using a `textarea` or something similar.

You can parse the contents this way:

```
function parseIt()
{
    splitValues = document.getElementById("input").value.split("\n");
    if (splitValues.length > 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("vals").style.display = 'inline';
        console.log(splitValues);
        for (i = 0; i < splitValues.length; i++)
            document.getElementById("vals").innerHTML += '<option value="' + splitValues[i].split(";")[0] + '">' + splitValues[i].split(";")[1] + '</option>';
    }
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/ZbJps/

---

If you have the input in a single line like this:

Then this function will do it:

```
function parseIt()
{
    splitValues = document.getElementById("input").value.split(";");
    if (splitValues.length > 0 && splitValues.length % 2 == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("vals").style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById("vals").innerHTML = "";
        for (i = 0; i < splitValues.length; i+=2)
            document.getElementById("vals").innerHTML += '<option value="' + splitValues[i] + '">' + splitValues[i+1] + '</option>';
    }
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/ZbJps/2/